# Joint distrubution of two random variables and their cov and cor

Tags: probability

Suppose X and Y are random variables with P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = $\frac{1}{2}$; P(Y = 1) = P(Y = -1) = $\frac{1}{2}$. Let c = P(X = 1 and Y = 1).

a) Determine the joint distribution of X and Y, Cov(X, Y), and Cor(X, Y).

b) For what value(s) of c are X and Y independent? For what value(s) of c are X and Y 100% correlated?

In this question I don't understand the meaning of P(X = 1) or P(Y = -1) and what is the meaning of the "determine the joint distribution of X an Y"? am I gonna calculate a function or fill a table?

Comment: Yes, a $2\times2$ table of numbers (or of algebraic  expressions in $c$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
\color{green}{P(X=x,Y=y)}   &  X=-1  & X=1   &\color{red}{P(Y=y)}   \\ \hline
Y=-1   &  \color{green}{c}  & \color{green}{\frac{1}{2} -c}   &  \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}     \\
Y=1    &  \color{green}{\frac{1}{2} -c }  &  \color{green}{ c} &  \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}    \\ \hline
\color{blue}{P(X=x)}  & \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}      &  \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}     & \\
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}